# Django-filter - filter model and related model

Tags: django, django-forms, django-filter

I have a database with books and libraries in a ManyToMany relationship. The libraries model contains a 'region' field. The user filters the books by region using a django-filter MultipleChoiceFilter as follows:

filterset.py:

```
class BookFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
library__region = django_filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(choices=CHOICES, label="Regions:", widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class' : 'myfieldclass'})
```

And the books print in the template with:

```
{% for book in filter %}
{{ book.name }}
{% for library in book.library.all %}{{ library.library }}{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This prints all books in the region, and all libraries where each of those books can be found. However, I don't want to print the libraries from other regions.

How can I apply the filter to print only those fields that match the region selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to print only the libraries of each book that belong to the selected region:

```
...
{% for library in book.library.all %}
    {% if library.library.region == request.GET.library__region %}
        {{ library.library }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This works when only one region is selected, but only uses the last region when more than one is chosen... Thanks for your help!

Comment: Okay, I've got it working using request.GET.getlist in the views. Thanks again!

Comment: Oops sorry I haven't seen that you were using a MultipleChoiceFilter!